# MySql: How to store files in database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

It can't seem to be uploaded to the database what is wrong with this.

here are my codes

this is the file connectiontwo.php to connect to the database

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "uphslletreviewer";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 ?>
```

this is the code so that it can be uploaded to the database

```
<?php
 include_once 'connectiontwo.php';
 if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
 {    

 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
 $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="uploads/";

 // new file size in KB
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 // new file size in KB

 // make file name in lower case
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 // make file name in lower case

 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {
 $sql="INSERT INTO module_let(module_desc,type,size)       VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
 $conn->query($sql);
 ?>
 <script>
  alert('successfully uploaded');
    window.location.href='indexsample.php?success';
    </script>
<?php
 }
else
 {
?>
<script>
alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='indexsample.php?fail';
    </script>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

your help will be much appreciated... Im new to php so i came here to ask for your help. thank you!

Comment: What doesn't work? Errors? What should happen? Please give more information. Also do not comcatenate SQL strings, always use parameters.

Comment: storing files in the database is usually not a good idea, why don't you use the filesystem and store only the path in your database ?

Comment: the final_file file_type and new_size can't be uploaded to the database

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ he is storing the path. What's the matter?

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a code review site where you ask what's wrong with your code, which makes your code off topic. You are supposed to debug your code yourself.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you're right, I was misled by the title

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the query was successful and if not, log/print the errors somewhere.

```
if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     // successful
} else {
     // Errorhandling
     // for finding the error a simple
     echo $conn->errno.": ".$conn->error
}
```

And as Sami already mentioned, you should really use Prepared Statements:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php